# Things For Mac - Any Way To Access From Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, things-for-mac

I'm getting ready to start a trial of [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) for the Mac. I have a Mac for personal use and an iPhone. At work, I have to run a PC with Windows XP. I also run Windows 7 at home on a PC. Is there any way (web based, etc) to sync Things tasks to a PC or view them online?

From watching the videos, the software looks excellent, but it would be a serious drawback for me if I couldn't get to tasks from a Windows computer.

Right now, I use [Remember the Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) which works reasonably well, but Things seems geared much more toward a GTD style of doing things.

Comment: G T D         ?

Comment: GTD == Getting Things Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it isn't possible to directly sync Things with your Windows machine; sorry.

(The Mac <-> iPhone sync works quickly and reliably, so if you sync your iPhone with your Windows box, perhaps there's some way to get your notes to Windows, through the Notes app, maybe. But that wouldn't be automatic or very convenient really...)

The above is based on following their blog, and looking at their [FAQ](http://culturedcode.com/things/wiki/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions_%28Things_Mac%29). Also, check [this question about syncing the iPhone version with Outlook](http://culturedcode.com/things/wiki/index.php/Syncing_with_Outlook%3F_%28FAQ%29); quote:

> A direct sync of to-dos between Things
>   on your iPhone and Outlook is
>   technically not possible at this time.
>   We hope that in the future Apple will
>   allow third parties to sync to-dos and
>   calendar events with MobileMe.
>
> The only way to sync with Outlook
>   would be via a Windows version of
>   Things. But there is no Windows
>   version yet. We'd love to have Things
>   on Windows as well and will consider
>   this as we move forward.

Also, there's no sync with MobileMe or any such internet-based service available either, at this point. I guess for now you'd just have to wait for either Outlook sync or Windows version of Things. :-|

Personally I use Things avidly on my home MacBook and on iPhone, but when at work (using Linux/Windows), I just stick to the iPhone version. (For work-related TODOs I use other things than Things - our scrum tool or personal textfiles - except if ideas pop-up when I'm not at work and I want to write them down.)

Answer (score 5):

No. There is only an OS X and iPhone application.

Things does store all its data as an XML file (in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Cultured Code/Things/Database.xml`), so it's <strike>theoretically</strike> possible to write a web interface to this.. Hm..

To elaborate on that "hm" - http://github.com/dbr/thingsweb/tree/master

Currently it's a simple read-only interface, written in Ruby using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com). Basically [download the code](http://github.com/dbr/thingsweb/tarball/master), extract, in a terminal go to the folder and run..

```
ruby thingsweb.rb
```

..then point your browser at http://localhost:4567/

Comment: Interesting idea...I wonder if they would give me an xsd for that?

:)

Comment: Above is still as of 2009, in Ruby. They [now] have an Applescript interface: docs referenced here: https://support.culturedcode.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2803572-using-applescript-with-things